How to force a section to start on the titlepage?
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[document]{ragged2e}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for inserting images
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tgtermes}


 \begin{document}

 
\begin{titlepage}
\centering

{\Large Project proposal}
\vspace{1cm}


{\LARGE\bfseries  title of the project}

\vspace{1cm}

{\large Isabelle YED}

\vspace{2cm}
\end{titlepage}
\section{Introduction}
dddd
\end{document}

The problem that I'm facing is that the introduction section jumps to the next page, leaving the title page blank.
How can I force the section to start on the title page?

The whole point of having a title page is to display prominently items such as title, author, maybe the author's institutional affiliation, and possibly a date on one and the same page -- and nothing else.
If you don't want this type of layout, you shouldn't be using a titlepage environment to begin with. What to do? I suggest you replace
\begin{titlepage}
\centering

{\Large Project proposal}
\vspace{1cm}

{\LARGE\bfseries Title of the project}

\vspace{1cm}

{\large Isabelle YED}

\vspace{2cm}
\end{titlepage}

with
\begin{center}
\Large Project proposal

\vspace{1cm}

\LARGE\bfseries Title of the project \mdseries

\vspace{1cm}

\large Isabelle YED

\end{center}

\vspace{2cm}

Note that because the \large, \Large, and \LARGE directives in your titlepage code are encased in TeX groups without \par at the end, these directives cannot work as intended.
